# get the contacts are sorted by popularity

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have a application and I want to show the contacts are sorted by popularity, for example the number of times that call to that contact. Another option: Sort by anyone with a picture. I want it done automatically without the user's choice! I would appreciate any help! Even on a partial answer!

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some of your own code so we can help.

Comment: the android contacts database has a column as times_contacted which save info about how many calls have been made with a particular contact..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query

```
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor cur2 = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
          null, null, null, "times_contacted desc");
  cur2.moveToFirst();

  int name=cur2.getColumnIndex("display_name");
  for(int i=0;i<cur2.getCount();i++){
    Log.v("name",""+cur2.getString(name));
    Log.v("times",""+cur2.getString(0));
    cur2.moveToNext();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you
It really helped!
And how do I sort by who has a picture - that is: put at the top, those who have picture

Answer (score 0):

If the contact is stored in a database you need to add an additional column where you will put in the number of times the contact was called.

When the user makes a call you need to add some code to increment the value stored in the "number of times the contact was called" column by +1.

When you list the contacts just sort them by the "number of times the contact was called" column.

Answer (score 0):

we donot have any such column to check whether contact has a photo or not... bt you can fetch the contact photo for eact contact if it exsists then place it at top otherwise not..

use this code to fetch the photo:(just pass the content resolver and id of each contact)

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    // InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```